# Return iterator for c type arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays

In the MRE https://godbolt.org/z/jdjPzdGeo, is there a way to return an iterator for `c` type arrays in `Func` like what you see with `std::array` in `Func2` and `Func3`? IDK what the return type would be.

Also, is there a way to make `Func` constexpr like in `Func2`?

Edit:
Add the code here

```
#include <array>

std::pair<int*, std::size_t>
Func() noexcept
{
    // why does constexpr instead of static not work?
    static int arr[]  = {1, 2};
    return { arr, std::size(arr) };
}

constexpr std::pair<std::array<int,2>::const_iterator, std::array<int,2>::const_iterator>
Func2() noexcept
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 2> arr  {{1, 2}};
    return { std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr) };
}

std::pair<std::array<int,2>::const_iterator, std::array<int,2>::const_iterator>
Func3() noexcept
{
    static std::array<int, 2> arr  {{1, 2}};
    return { std::cbegin(arr), std::cend(arr) };
}

int main()
{
    Func();
    Func2();
    Func3();
}
```

Comment: please include the code in the question. When something "does not work" you should show the code that doesn't work and the resulting compiler error

Comment: Please post all code as text in the question.  Links may expire making the question useless for future users of SO.  See (2) here [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin)

Comment: `Func2` is wrong, it cannot be called in constant expression [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/97sTjGKGa).

Comment: Code moved here. It compiles but I want to make `Func` behave more like the other 2 and am expecting the return type to be an iterator of some sort. int* works for std::begin but what about std::cbegin?

Comment: @domoremath Did you try it? `std::cbegin` and `std::cend` work just fine for C arrays. But as noted the code is invalid anyway.

Comment: yes I tried it and it compiles but the const iter doesn't work.

Comment: @domoremath What do you mean by “doesn’t work”? As multiple people have pointed out, your code is simply invalid, but that has nothing to do with the iterator type, nor is it specific to the C array code. *All* your functions are invalid.

Comment: I later tried accessing the array values outside the function and it wasn't working with const int*. I don't see how the 2 static ones are invalid though. They work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Return iterator for c type arrays?
>
> IDK what the return type would be.

The iterator type for arrays is a pointer. for example, if you have an array of `int`, then the iterator type for the array is `int*`.

> and am expecting the return type to be an iterator of some sort.

`int*` is an iterator.

> int* works for std::begin but what about std::cbegin?

If you want a constant iterator, that would be `const int*`.

---

Your `Func2` returns dangling iterators as far as I can tell. Don't return iterators, references etc. to objects with automatic storage duration.